# Mathematics free online lectures in British

Tags: online-resources

I am pretty sure this is a weird (and perhaps hard or unique) question, but hopefully it is understandable. The title is a mixed one, but it is primarily about math.

Specifically, I am looking for sets of free mathematics online video lectures delivered by any person who speaks in British accent.

I have course materials that I need to learn, but at the same time I would like to learn British accent too as a hobby. Instead of learning them separately, it saves time a lot. The course materials are Lebesgue/measure theory related, or number theory related, but not limited to those, as long as they are college math.

I have searched youtube and unsurprisingly did not find the lectures with exact criteria. The Oxford channel provides some, but else:
- either there is no material exactly as above,
- or the lectures are not delivered in set (meaning one video one whole story/topic, although this is fine too)
- or (weirdly for me) many lecturers speak no British accent.

Is there any other channels, or websites, satisfying the conditions?

Primary condition: free online video lectures in college math delivered in British accent

Secondary/optional condition: they are Lebesgue/measure theory related or number theory related, or any higher math topic.

Thank you in advance. Stay safe!

Comment: FYI, there are quite a few British accents. Did you have a preference for one in particular, or would any of them do? For example, would you be happy with some kind of Scottish accent?

Comment: This i part one of an excellent set of lectures on measure theory https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xZ69KEg7ccU. I think the lecturer might be German, his English is excellent and he probably sounds like he normally does, except in English. Don't worry about the accent, sound like yourself.

Comment: How about [the pretentious approach to analytic number theory](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RpuhtlFqFL) or John Conway's [surreal numbers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1eAmxgINXrE)?

Comment: @user797616 Thank you. I kinda prefer the standard BBC one.

Comment: @Paul Thanks for the link. I expected comment like yours haha. I honestly am not learning English. I have. I sound like myself already. Again, I study accent for hobby.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Wow thank you very much. The one from John Conway works. The first link does not work (unavailable vid it says).

Comment: Try [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RpuhtlFqFLw); I might have inadvertently truncated the address above

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Got it. I'm even very interested in the topic. I imagine there should be a lot more. Thanks. Would've upvoted twice.

Comment: https://youtu.be/2un9rO2ZF4g A light hearted take here.

Comment: https://youtu.be/SDGOLWpCxng These are great lectures. There is a series on Lebesque measure that I can't find now.

Comment: As has been alluded to there are many English accents alone let alone British.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [John Conway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Horton_Conway) was an English mathematician (who spent the second half of his career at Princeton) known for the Game of Life among other things.  He died recently due to COVID-19.  [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1eAmxgINXrE) he lectures about surreal numbers.
2. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RpuhtlFqFLw) is Andrew Granville giving a lecture entitled "the pretentious approach to analytic number theory."